# Mardia test out put

Tags: normality-assumption

I run `MardiyaTest` for a data set. I want to get only `p.value.skew` and `p.value.kurt`. I don't know how to get this. I used `result$"p.value.kurt"` and some other ways but has a error `Error in result$p.value : $ operator not defined for this S4 class`. I am wondering if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this function returns S4 class object, `result@p.value.kurt` and `result@p.value.skew` should work.